# What status code should be used if somebody sends a GET request to a POST endpoint?

Tags: rest, post-redirect-get

I have a URL:

```
/item/delete/
```

It accepts a POST request. When it gets the POST request, it deletes the item indicated in the POST payload, and does the [PRG dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

What do I do if it receives a GET request? I'd like for it to return some kind of status code -- probably something in the 400 range? -- but I'm not sure which to use, or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Would love some RESTful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use: 405 Method Not Allowed

See section 10.4.6 of https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: Well look at that. Thanks.